# Patching Asp.net Mvc2 AntiForgeryToken exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, reflection, patch, antiforgerytoken

Some background to my issue:

It appears that there is a change/bug in Mvc2 concerning `ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute`.

When upgrading from Mvc1 to Mvc2, users with an active session will receive the following error when they request a page using `ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute`:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.Triplet' to type 'System.Object[]'.

The issue is documented [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/james_crowley/archive/2010/03/18/beware-upgrade-to-asp-net-mvc-2-0-with-care-if-you-use-antiforgerytoken.aspx).

After upgrading to Mvc2, we anticipate that we will be seriously affected by this issue. I have coded a fix derived from the code in the comments (documented below for posterity). At the moment this code is invoked by creating a subclass of `Controller` and `AsyncController` overriding the Initialize method in order to correct the problem. e.g.

```
public class FixedController:Controller
{
    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);
        this.FixAntiForgeryTokenMvc1ToMvc2(requestContext); //extension
    }
}

internal static class ControllerEx
{
    public static void FixAntiForgeryTokenMvc1ToMvc2(
        this Controller controller,
        RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        var cc = new ControllerContext(requestContext,
                                       controller);
        var antiForgeryAttribute = new ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute();
        try
        {
            antiForgeryAttribute.OnAuthorization(new AuthorizationContext(cc));
        }
        catch (HttpAntiForgeryException forgeryException)
        {
            var castException = forgeryException.InnerException;
            if (castException != null
                && castException is InvalidCastException
                && castException.Message.StartsWith(
                       "Unable to cast object of type"
                       + " 'System.Web.UI.Triplet' to type"
                       + " 'System.Object[]'"))
            {
                var responseTokenCookieNames =
                    controller
                        .Response
                        .Cookies
                        .Cast<Cookie>()
                        .Select(c => c.Name)
                        .Where(n => n.Contains("RequestVerificationToken"));
                foreach (var s in responseTokenCookieNames)
                {
                    var cookie = controller.Response.Cookies[s];
                    if (cookie != null)
                    {
                        cookie.Value = "";
                    }
                }
                var requestTokenCookieNames =
                    controller
                        .Request
                        .Cookies
                        .Cast<String>()
                        .Where(n => n.Contains("RequestVerificationToken"))
                        .ToList();
                foreach (var c in requestTokenCookieNames)
                {
                    controller.Request.Cookies.Remove(c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The knock on effect of this is that I must alter all my controller classes to derive from my new, corrected Controller subclasses. This seems quite intrusive for code that intend to deprecate in about a month's time.

So, coming to my question, I'd like to know if there is a less intrusive means of patching existing classes such that downstream users of the class do not have to be altered, perhaps using reflection?

Comment: Can you disconnect everyone before the upgrade?

Comment: We'd prefer not to if possible.

Comment: i know it doesn't help you in your quest. we were lucky to be able to inform all our users to clear their cache/cookies before we did a similar upgrade about 3 months ago. i went round in circles trying to get a viable solution to the potential problems. in the end (it was a line of business app with only 50 users) we just emailled them with instructions on how to clear the 'debris'. of course, if your's is a public website, then the above is possibly the only course of action. i'll closely monitor this as a one place fix for some up and coming work is of interest to me.

Comment: also, you could use a basecontroller and have all your other controllers inherit from that, thereby only coding it once and then having the 'luxury' of removing it from a single location once the migration was complete (in say 4 months time - or whatever). this would be my 1st angle of attack (using code similar to your OP)

Comment: @jim: I don't think clearing cache and cookies is necessary. The anti-forgery-token is just a hidden input in the page. When we upgraded, we hardly had any problems; most people that got an error just reloaded the page and then were able to submit just fine.

Comment: We're very public. Notifying our users is impossible. @Esteban, the AFT is also published to the client in session-cookie form. Reloading does not make the problem go away because the session remains. The problem does go away after restarting the browser, but we can't expect our users to do this naturally, leaving several hundred users with what looks like a broken website.

Comment: @spender: I understand. However, it seems a little silly to me to write code for what will only be a problem once. In our case (a small public site: 40k visitors/month) we decided it wasn't a big deal; we figured most people would close the browser and try again later. I understand this may not be the case for you. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Spender,

rather than code every controller, use a basecontroller and inherit from that along the lines of:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);
        FixAntiForgeryTokenMvc1ToMvc2(this, requestContext);
    }
    private static void FixAntiForgeryTokenMvc1ToMvc2(
        Controller controller, RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        // stuff ....
    }
}
```

and in your 'normal' controllers, just have:

```
public class NormalController : BaseController
{
    // all the previous stuff
}
```

give it a go...

Comment: That's the current way that I am doing it. It still requires changing all controllers to derive from the new base.

Comment: ok - in that case, wouldn't the single change to your base controller trickle down to everything that's inherited from it??. of course, i'm assuming that you've 'always' had a base controller in place, hence my casual suggestion. otherwise, i guess the jury's still out then :(

Comment: Sure... that's exactly the plan, so as such things are pretty nicely under control. I was really wondering on a general level if theres a less intrusive method of patching bad code. Until somebody says different, I'm fairly happy I've taken the best approach.

Comment: spender, imho, i think you've taken the most widely understood approach and thus prolly the most pragmatic for what is after all a transitory situation.